# google cloud engine metadata query

Tags: google-app-engine, metadata, google-cloud-platform

I have set a metadata groupip="10.0.0.2 10.0.0.3 10.0.0.4" in the project metadata. I am trying to query it using the following command:

curl 'http://metadata/computeMetadata/v1/projectid/groupip/' -H "Metadata-Flavor: Google"

As answer instead of the IP's I am getting the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=en>
  <meta charset=utf-8>
  <meta name=viewport content="initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
  <title>Error 404 (Not Found)!!1</title>
  <style>
*{margin:0;padding:0}html,code{font:15px/22px arial,sans-serif}html{background:#fff;color:#222;padding:15px}bod
y{margin:7% auto 0;max-width:390px;min-height:180px;padding:30px 0 15px}* > body{background:url(//www.google.com/im
ages/errors/robot.png) 100% 5px no-repeat;padding-right:205px}p{margin:11px 0 22px;overflow:hidden}ins{color:#777;t
ext-decoration:none}a img{border:0}@media screen and (max-width:772px){body{background:none;margin-top:0;max-width:
none;padding-right:0}}#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp
.png) no-repeat;margin-left:-5px}@media only screen and (min-resolution:192dpi){#logo{background:url(//www.google.c
om/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat 0% 0%/100% 100%;-moz-border-image:url(//w
 ww.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) 0}}@media only screen and (-webkit-min-d
evice-pixel-ratio:2){#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.
png) no-repeat;-webkit-background-size:100% 100%}}#logo{display:inline-block;height:54px;width:150px}
  </style>
  <a href=//www.google.com/><span id=logo aria-label=Google></span></a>
  <p><b>404.</b> <ins>That’s an error.</ins>
  <p>The requested URL <code>/computeMetadata/v1/projectid/groupip/</code> was not found on this server.  <ins>Th
at’s all we know.</ins>
```

Comment: http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/project/attributes/groupip?

Comment: Nope, it's not working

Comment: Works perfectly for me: curl 'http://metadata/computeMetadata/v1/project/attributes/groupip' -H "Metadata-Flavor: Google"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the same way that you get an instance's metadata via instance/attributes/xyz, so you can get the project's metadata via project/attributes/xyz.

```
curl http://metadata/computeMetadata/v1/project/attributes/groupip -H "Metadata-Flavor: Google"
```

[image: Project metadata: groupip]
To make sure you actually added the project-level metadata correctly, list *all* project attributes:[image: Project metadata: all]
And more generally, keep shortening the URL to list ancestors:[image: Metadata hierarchy]

Comment: it does not works for me, I am getting the exact same error as in the issue description.

Comment: What happens if you ask for *all* the project attributes with curl 'http://metadata/computeMetadata/v1/project/attributes/' -H "Metadata-Flavor: Google"?

Comment: Interesting, running the exact same commands I get the following: http://prntscr.com/bf3nrj

Comment: Do you get attributes if you use: curl http://metadata/computeMetadata/v1/project/?recursive=true  -H "Metadata-Flavor: Google". Beyond that I would try launching a new instance and see if this repros.

Comment: running in recursive=true I am also getting nothing.

Comment: I recommend you reboot the instance and retry. This could be an unusual bug in the metadata server. If that fails, then launch a new instance with all the defaults and re-test. That should work. Then try to understand what differences there might be between your instance and the working one.